# How to return numpy array of minimums of k intervals within numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a way of returning a numpy array of size k containing the minimum value of k equally-sized intervals of an array?

For instance:

```
k = 3
arr = np.array([2,3,4,1,5,1,7,2,5,6,5,4,3,4,6,7,0,7])
mins = min_k(arr, k)//mins = np.array([2,1,2,4,3,0])
```

I can only think of using a for loop to iterate over the array by intervals of k and appending the min of that interval to a new array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the size of arr is multiple of `k`:

```
arr.reshape(-1, k).min(1)
# array([2, 1, 2, 4, 3, 0])
```

Otherwise, you can pad the `arr` to length of multiple of `k` with the edge values, reshape it to `(-1, k)` (`k` columns), and then take the row min:

```
k = 3
arr = np.array([2,3,4,1,5,1,7,2,5,6,5,4,3,4,6,7,0,7])

pad_width = 0 if len(arr) % k == 0 else k - len(arr) % k
np.pad(arr, (0, pad_width), 'edge').reshape(-1, k).min(1)
# array([2, 1, 2, 4, 3, 0])
```

Comment: `arr.reshape(-1, k).min(1)` gives the same answer though?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Yes. Trying to have a slightly more general answer here.